# How do I get the value of an attribute of class B from an array of pointers that point to type B objects and is an attribute in class A?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have to make an array of pointers that point to type B objects and that array must be an attribute of 
class A. When I am trying to print the code of B I am getting no result. 
In main() I am trying to call for D object the getBobj method that returns a pointer at a B object and then call the getCode() method to get and print the code.

```
class B
{
    string code;

public:
    .
    .
    .
    B(int i)
    {
       code = i;
    }
    string getCode ()
    {
        return code;
    }
    .
    .
    .
};


class A
{
    int numOfB;
    B **objB;

public:



    void setBobj (const A *obj_a, B *obj_b_arr)
    {
        delete [] objB;
        objB = new B * [obj_a->getNumOfBobj()];
        memcpy (objB, obj_b_arr, obj_a->getNumOfBobj());
    }


    B * A::getBobj (const A &obja)
    {
        return *objB;
    }

};

int main ()
{

    .
    .
    .
    .
    B b1(1);
    B b2(2);
    B b3(3);
    B b[] = {b1, b2, b3};

    D.setBobj(&D, &b);
    cout << (D.getBobj(D))->getCode(); //Nothing gets printed
}
```

Comment: Where does B.code get set .? Not enough here for anyone to help.

Comment: There is no need to see setters and getters. I tried to keep my question simple.

Comment: Don't simplify too much take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for advice on how to ask a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    objB = new B * [obj_a->getNumOfBobj()];
    memcpy (objB, obj_b_arr, obj_a->getNumOfBobj());
```

This is (probably) wrong. You are allocating an array of the size of the previous number of Bobjs in A when setting a new array. You probably meed to pass in the number of Bs to `setBobj`.

Also, this is an unholy mess of C and C++ style coding. You probably want a vector instead of raw allocated arrays, and use std::copy instead of memcpy, etc.

Also you either need to make your functions static or even better, don't pass in the address of D when calling setBobj/getBObj - just use `this`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use vectors. Thank you